# Unexpected token error on

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an error on my script below.  It says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

I am not sure why that is or what I am missing

```
        <script> //[CDATA[
if (%%GLOBAL_Availability%% == "") {'error is here
    document.getElementById("ShopButton").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#ShopButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
      window.location.href='%%GLOBAL_Availability%%';
    },false);
}
    //]]> </script>
```

Here is how it shows on Chrome:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what do you expect `%%GLOBAL_Availability%%` to return?

Comment: You need to enclose the Url in quotation marks. Either `"` or `'` for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you haven't put `%%GLOBAL_Availability%%` inside quotation marks.

```
if ('%%GLOBAL_Availability%%' == "") {
    document.getElementById("ShopButton").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#ShopButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
      window.location.href='%%GLOBAL_Availability%%';
    },false);
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by `%%GLOBAL_Availability%%`. It is not a valid variable name nor a valid url.

> A variable name must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.

Comment: thanks I put the marks and it worked fine.